# OCaml - declaring n-dimensional arrays

Tags: ocaml

I want to create 3-dimensional array in ocaml. Here's what I tried to do:

```
let dp = Array.make n (Array.make n (Array.make k (-1))
```

However it doesn't work - changing a value dp[0][0][0] changes all values dp[i][j][0]. So how to create matrix with distinct arrays, not with copies of the same one?

Comment: Look at : http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/faq/core.en.html. Quoting this url : The allocation of a new array has two phases. First, the initial value is computed; then this value is written in each element of the new array. That's why the line which is allocated by Array.make 3 0 is unique and physically shared by all the lines of the array m.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Array.make n v` will just replicate the second argument `n` times. In other words, it will assign it in a cycle to each element. Since arrays (as well as all other heap-allocated values) are passed by reference, all cells will point to the same array. You need to use the `Array.init` function, that will call user provided function for each element:

```
let dp = Array.init n (fun _ -> Array.init n (fun _ -> (Array.make k 0)))
```

But, for real multidimensional numeric code, you shouldn't use arrays, but instead use `Bigarray` module. Here is the example:

```
open Bigarray
let dp = Array3.create int c_layout 3 3 3
dp.{0,0,0} <- 1
```