# How do you initialize an array with stacks?

Tags: types, syntax, ocaml

Attempt:

```
let symbol_table = Array.make 256 Stack.create()
```

However, I don't specify the type of the stack when creating the array, so I want to know how you would do this by specifying the type of the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Array.init](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Array.html#VALinit) to create an array of *different* stack instances

```
Array.init 256 (fun _ -> Stack.create ())
```

If you will do `Array.make 256 (Stack.create ())` then you will create one instance of a stack, and assign it to each element of the array. Thus `Stack.push 4 symbol_table.(0)` will push a symbol into all 256 stacks.

See also a relevant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032848/ocaml-declaring-n-dimensional-arrays/28033030#28033030).

Answer (score 1):

The type will be inferred when you use it:

```
let symbol_table = Array.make 256 (Stack.create ())
let () = Stack.push 4 symbol_table.(0)
```

But you can also specify the type on the let binding, if you need to:

```
let symbol_table : int Stack.t array = Array.make 256 (Stack.create ())
```

Edit: As noted in the comments you should be using `Array.init` to initialize the array with 256 *separate* instances, rather than the 256 references to the same stack instance you'd get with `Array.make`:

```
let symbol_table : int Stack.t array = Array.init 256 (fun _ -> Stack.create ())
```

Comment: Note that this code creates an array of references to the same stack which is problematic since `Stack.t` is a mutable data type. `Array.init 256 (fun _ -> Stack.create ()) `avoids this problem.